# W3WP.exe - CPU spikes to 100% then falls to 0% resulting in poor performance

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an existing asp.net app that worked for months without issues.

**The problem**

Suddenly, (after a new code release) once every day or two, the CPU starts to go from 100% utilization to 0%, and back and forth, every few seconds.

While this is happening, aspnet requests are being queued up, execution time and wait time increases drastically.

Restart of WWW Publishing Service “solves” the issue (for a day or so). Pre-emptive restart of the service also helps.

**My guess at the cause**

Since this started after a new release, I blame the new code but I am looking for clues what it could be. My best guess would be **memory leak** but memory usage of w3wp.exe never goes over 6.5GB and there is spare physical memory, and I do store a lot of stuff in the session.

**Can anyone offer a clue?**

Debugging IIS is a daunting task and one I have little experience with so I am hoping someone else had a similar issue and can provide a clue.

**Some more notes/clues**
When restarting WWW service at the time of this issue, the stopping of the service takes a long time. A good two minutes.

Comment: How long does the 100% spike last before it dies out ?

Comment: "How long does the 100% spike last before it dies out ? "
--> just a few seconds at most. but the application slow down is very noticible and sparatic

Comment: Why would you think a memory leak would cause a CPU spike? Sounds like there's a loop spinning out of control somewhere..

Comment: @SP 
well, I suppose it is possible that there is contention for memory. It could be a loop spinning out of control, by why so rarely? all of the different parts of the app are used all the time, i think i have eliminated a possibility of a rarely run function causing it already... so I am lost...

Comment: 6.5MB or GB of memory usage? 6.5GB is pretty crazy.

Answer (score 0):

w3wp.exe is part of IIS, but doesn't actually do much work. The 100% CPU utilization is from the code that is running inside of that process. That's *your* code.

If you have free memory, then any memory leak doesn't matter. Ignore memory leaks for now.

Can you reproduce this problem on a Development machine? If so, then you need to profile the application while it's running so you can find out where the application is spending its time.

Comment: thanks John. I guess I will have to do that. Can't say i am looking forward to it however :)

Comment: Not looking forward to what? Performance profiling can be very cool. A profiler can give you answers about your code that you didn't were questions.

Comment: There is at least one way that you can run out of memory in a .net process but still look like you have free memory available. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yunjin/archive/2004/01/27/63642.aspx That is clearly not the problem here though as it results in OOM errors.

Comment: Take a look at `ANTS Performance Profiler` and `ANTS Memory Profiler`. Inexpensive, but excellent for identifying bottlenecks in your code.